# Run full load in washing machine, find water on floor by drain

Tags: water, drain

It's a house new to us but 18 years old. We ran the washing machine for the first time with a full load and came back to find water around the drain pipe and on the floor. Makes sense that the drain is clogged and backed up but it hasn't happened since with three more loads.

Is it possible that that one load cleared the drain lines from lack of use over some period of time? We don't know how long the house was vacant but it couldn't have been more than three months as a guess.

EDIT: The potential answer to the problem involves how the washing machine was transported. According to Whirlpool, the machine was to have transport bolts installed to hold down the drum. Having taken a long trip from Houston to St. Louis could have cause the drum to jostle around enough to cause damage to some hoses or support. Worse, possibly, is that I had transported it from storage to the house on its backside, the only method I had available to me.

I hope to have a service guy out by the end of this week to view the bill. Potential cost to fix ranges from $150 to $450 but that's still cheaper than buying a new one which was what my son would have had to do if this wasn't given to him.

Comment: Was the floor drain back up at the same time as the tub backup while taking a shower. If this is the same house you may have a partial clog below that area of the drain. With both the washer daring while a shower is running could cause it to back up. If this is the case the drain line will need to be power snaked or jetted to clear the lines.

Comment: @EdBeal That was my thought, too. That he may have been running the washer and showering at the same time.

Comment: Just because the house was occupied 3 months ago doesn't mean the occupants owned a working washing machine.